# WKWebView evalulateJavascript in context of sub frame

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How do you execute javascript in the context of a frame other than the main frame? Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain more :)

Comment: An iFrame which has a separate domain? You get cross-domain errors if you do it purely though JS.